# How can I reduce eye strain?

Tags: technology, offices

I work using a computer for 8 hours a day. Sometimes my eyes hurt. My friend recommended that I should use eyestrain-reducing software. Is software a good way to solve this problem? If so, what are the important things to look for?  If not, what else can I do instead? I'm not wearing any glasses.

Comment: If you have windows 10, just turn on windows night light.  Search your start menu for `night light`.  It reduces the blue on your screen.  Also I am 90% certain this is the wrong site for this.  But I like to help.

Comment: Low screen brightness helps a lot as well.

Comment: This question is attracting spam flags, presumably because of the product link.  If you mean to ask a more general question about reducing eyestrain, I suggest you ask about that rather than asking about a specific product.

Comment: @Monica Cellio already edited my question.

Comment: When was the last time you went to an optician for an eye test? Did you mention the eye strain?

Comment: simple, turn on the "blue light reduction" system.

Comment: .,.. exactly as @TrevorD said.   Also, most monitors (and now all, say, Apple devices) have this totally built-in at the panel level.  Use it.  It's great.

Comment: Do you have enough sleep? Because of not enough sleep also one of the causes of your eye strain.

Comment: By getting proper rest, sleep and nutrition. More info from hard experience here: https://nav9.medium.com/the-real-cure-for-eye-strain-6483490d150f. The "blue light" and all kinds of special spectacles are excellent ways of distracting you from the real cause of the strain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things I can suggest:

- Get your eyes checked out.  Your vision may be OK for most tasks, but a slight vision issue over time can cause headaches and eyestrain.
- If possible, take your gaze off the monitor at least once every 20 minutes
- Try adjusting the monitor settings and workspace settings (again if possible).  Does a brighter/dimmer monitor help or hurt?  Does brighter/dimmer ambient lighting help or hurt?

Comment: Also, what kind of ambient light is there? If you're in the dark (gaming? but I'm guessing not as you said its work), that will really hurt after a few days. Screen glare? As Ocie Mitchell said, take eye breaks, and make sure you spend time looking at something a good distance away. Re adjusting monitor settings, check the physical distance from yourself. Also screen res & text size. Colours? Try white/other on black.

Answer (score 9):

> My friend recommended that I should use eyestrain-reducing software. Is software a good way to solve this problem? If so, what are the important things to look for? If not, what else can I do instead?

For medical advice, don't follow recommendations of a friend, and don't ask what to do from strangers on the internet. Often the recommendation on workplace on a problem is "go see a lawyer".

My advice is **go see a doctor**. Yes, it's likely it's nothing serious and some simple adjustments will do. But it also might be a symptom of more serious things.

15 years ago, I had similar problems. I did go see a doctor, and it turned out to be caused by type 2 diabetes. Once I got medication, I no longer had problems with my eyes while using a computer for hours.

Again, don't get worried, chances are the symptoms are nothing serious. But why take the risk?

Comment: While I agree about seeing a doctor, my experience and other people's experiences say that doctors don't really know how to cure eye strain. However, with proper sleep, rest and nutrition obtained over a period of many months, the strain will definitely reduce. More here: https://nav9.medium.com/the-real-cure-for-eye-strain-more-experiences-7f4c1c552d5a

Answer (score 1):

I used to suffer a lot of eye strain as well. I am working at a computer all day as well. What actually was my issue (apart from not having short breaks now and then), was actually that I needed vision training. My eye muscles had a tougher time focusing on something rather close than optimal - as a PC monitor for example. I went to a specialist that gave me some exercises to fix this, which solved my problem.

Comment: It would make sense to list those exercises IMO

Comment: I thought about it, but the exercises one would benefit from, varies alot from person to person, and I am no expert in this area, so I chose not to share them.

Answer (score 0):

Many comment points out "blue light reduction", I think that's great for working a few hours before sleeping, to not tricking your blain into thinking it's still noon. However, I have my doubts on its effect on eyestrain.

Depending on whether your work is text-bases or not, you may choose to use light or dark backgrounds. Generally speaking, staring at a white creen for hours will have a really bad outcome. Many programs such as Excel or WPS implement an "eye-protection mode" that change the classical white background for a greenish one.

For software development tools, completely black background are often available. Experiment with the different possibilities and pick the one that works best for you!

Finally, periodic short breaks are critical!

Comment: Sorry David, but the blue light hype has been proven to be wrong by researchers. Periodic breaks by closing the eyes are indeed good...and getting 8 hours of uninterrupted sleep and a well balanced diet of properly cooked food is also necessary. I suffered and recovered from chronic eye strain. None of the nonsense of eye drops and special spectacles helped.

Comment: @Nav Note that my answers hasn't talked about the effect of blue light reduction on sleep being true or false. I just said that other answers have mentioned this.

Comment: Oh ok. Cool. btw, there seem to be quite a bit of people suffering: https://nav9.medium.com/the-real-cure-for-eye-strain-more-experiences-7f4c1c552d5a

Answer (score 0):

As someone who suffers from the same thing and I always give my eyes I checkup I have few advices for :

1. Go see a doctor ASAP, you may be allergic to something and it has nothing to do with computer or anything related, so it's better to pay your eyes' doctor a visit.
2. When you are using a computer, your eyes don't blink a lot which causes them to be dry due to that, when you eyes are dry you start feeling as if there's sand in them or something like that, you have few solutions, either don't use laptop for a long period of time in one go, or there are some artificial tears that you can buy at a drug store, they're good to prevent your eyes from getting dry, and you can use them once every two hours or something, it depends on what you bought and beware of allergic reactions.
3. Blue light, since it's found that it can cause damage to the eyes, there are Blue light reduction glasses, you can use that, or you can simply turn on Night Mode in your laptop, it's the same thing (In case you have good eyesight, otherwise you should buy glasses), but beware of UV light, there's the blue light from your screen and there's the sun, so you should take good care of your eyes because you only have 2 of them and no money can buy that.

Those are some informations that I've gathered from my doctor since I also use a laptop for at least 8 hours a day. But the best thing you should do is get an appointment and see a doctor, he has better knowledge and experience and he can help you in case there are other things that you didn't know about your eyes.

EDIT :

1. I just saw that you do not wear glasses, I advise you to buy them (blue light reduction ones) even if you find that your vision is OK, leave them besides your computer, it doesn't hurt to wear them, better safe than sorry.
2. There's another problem that I have with my eyes, I don't know the term in english, but in general, my eyes are doing great effort to gather an image, and that effort makes them tired and with time it gives a headache etc ... so I'm wearing glasses to reduce the strain on them, ask your doctor later because you may have the same problem

Wish you good health.

Comment: Blue light has been proven not to be the cause of eye strain. Google for research on it. Blue light reduction glasses are just a lot of hype. The actual cure for eye strain is to get 8 hours of uninterrupted sleep each night, to close your eyes after 20 minutes of computer use and wait until the strain reduces and to obtain a well balanced diet of properly cooked food. I know this from a decade of chronic eye strain and the eventual recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the cause of the strain:

If you are using a font that is too small, you tend to try to focus.  This affects the muscles in your eyes that change the shape of your eyeball.

- Try increasing the screen font size to the next size up.

I find that newer LED monitors are too bright, and too high contrast.

- There usually is a button that brings up an on screen menu where you can control brightness and contrast.  Try playing with this.
- Try a different colour scheme.  I do all my file editing in a window using dark blue type on a wheat coloured background.

There is often not enough room light.  Whenever you look away from your monitor, your eyes dilate to get more light, then contract again when you look back to the screen.

- Increase room lighting in your normal field of view.
- Dim your screen.

If your monitor sits so that one edge of it is nearer your eyes than the other edge, then your eyes have to constantly shift focus as they move around the screen

- Move your monitor so that the centre of the monitor is at right angles to your line of vision.

If your eyes are used to reading at a distance of 14-16 inches (common position to hold a book or magazine) and your computer monitor is at 24 inches, then you are focusing at the wrong distance for you.

- Try moving your monitors closer to your eyes.  Note that many monitors doing this will also mean you are looking down more.  Put a phone book or two under your monitor.